# return mid string and count

Tags: mysql

I have a concatenated string in a field that I now need to pull statistics from. 
What is needed is a count of how many records are from each county in Maryland.

fieldname county_city is stored as follows: 
Frederick,MD - Frederick County - 21701

```
//State
trim(substring(SUBSTRING_INDEX(county_city,',',-1),1,3)) as state

//city
SUBSTRING_INDEX(county_city,'-',1) as city_state

//zip code
SUBSTRING_INDEX(county_city,'-',-1) as zipcode,
```

but getting the county has been eluding me! 
I have an idea that getting the count will elude me as well.

Comment: _“I have a concatenated string in a field”_ – and that is the _start_ of your troubles. You should not have the data stored like that to begin with.

Comment: _“but getting the county has been eluding me”_ - well you’d need to find the positions of the two `-` first then I suppose, [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) can probably help with that. Of course the whole thing will come crumbling down, should any of the characters you consider “delimiters” here (comma, minus) ever occur inside the data (like maybe a county name that contains such a minus-“hyphen”, or similar.)

Comment: Yes, I considered separating that field but never thought there would be a request for statistics using that information. I got as far as adding the fields separated and should have stuck with that idea. I started changing the code for that last week after the request. Fortunately no counties in maryland have a dash so once I figure this out and update query is in the future.

Comment: How many records do you have here? Might make more sense to do this aggregation outside of MySQL. In PHP or a comparable server-side language, taking this string apart into its components would likely be a lot easier, than trying to handle this with MySQL’s rudimentary string functions.

Comment: Thinking this through, what I have is the user enters a zip code and using javascript, the list filters and displays the city, state, etc (concatenated). Saves the user time in filling all that info out. I can use the code I have above for zip code and fill the fields separately. using an update query and joining the data table and zip code table. The zip code table holds the separate fields (city, state, county, zip) I'd rather correct the big mistake I made not separating them from the beginning. This is a new database so I only have around 600 records.

Comment: Update: It was a little work but I resolved the issue by changing the structure and getting rid of the concatenation. I'll keep reminding myself to never keep a string of data in a field. :)

Answer (score 0):

With string functions is a 2 step procedure:

```
set @s = 'Frederick,MD - Frederick County - 21701';
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(@s, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@s, '-' ,1)) + 2), '-', 1));
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bZdFhQM7PEKRr39KS8BZA5/0).
Result:

```
Frederick County
```